# How to find and replace in Notepad++ while before exact text?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file that contains thousands of lines (json columns) like this:

```
"128",
            "drugName_en": "Ampy 500mg Capsules",
            "drugName_ar": "امبي 500 مجم كبسول",
            "scientificDrugId": "959",
            "proxyDrugId": "01",
            "prodCompDrugId": "06",
            "pack": "2x10Capsules",
            "unit": "باكت",
            "price": "0",
            "discount": "00",
            "categoryId": "15",
            "image": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/medical-health/256/medicine-box-icon.png"
        },
        "129",
            "drugName_en": "Ampy C 10*10 C 500mg Capsules",
            "drugName_ar": "امبي سي 500 مجم 10*10 كبسول",
            "scientificDrugId": "36",
            "proxyDrugId": "01",
            "prodCompDrugId": "06",
            "pack": "10x10Capsules",
            "unit": "باكت",
            "price": "2267",
            "discount": "00",
            "categoryId": "15",
            "image": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/medical-health/256/medicine-box-icon.png"
        },
```

I need to replace each `,` which is before `"drugName_en"` with `:{`

Could this be done in Notepad++?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Replace `,\s+("drugName_en")` with `: { \1` using regexp replacements

Comment: Thank you Nick, that just worked as a charm

Answer (score 1):

This does the job, preserving the linebreak (whatever it is):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `,(\R)(?=\s+"drugName_en")`
- Replace with: `:{$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
,                   # a comma
(\R)                # group 1, any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \s+                 # 1 or more white spaces
    "drugName_en"       # literally
)                   # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
/{                  # literally
$1                  # content of group 1, the linebreak
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

this is not possible in notepad++ but it is possible in sublime text editor.i have tried it and it is completely work just try Sublime Text editor.

[Download Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)

[image: check out]

Comment: I have done it with this 
(Replace ,\s+("drugName_en") with : { \1 using regexp replacements) answer  from Nick

and it worked like a charm

Thank you

Comment: okay no problem and Sublime is best for text editing so you can use it.

Comment: Where have you that's not possible with Notepad++?

Comment: i tried it in notepad++ but it not working but sublime easily do it.